# How to check if variable type is equal to defined type

Tags: typescript

I have a type that has some properties and I want to check if a variable type is equal to it or not.

```
export type ITestType = {
  select: {
    options?: any[];
    multiple?: boolean;
  };
  string: undefined;
  hidden: undefined;
  date: {
    format: string;
    withOriginalDate?: boolean;
  };
};


const test :ITestType['select'] = {}
```

I already tried:

```
console.log(typeof test === ITestType['select'])
```

and:

```
console.log(test instanceof ITestType['select'])
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=49&pln=19&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCSAVYBnGHmoC8cA3gFBxzbAA2wAxjAFykWVwRgwCWEAdtgD8LAIZ9EAbQC6AbjaUAtgFcaPMHWFwARhAh0xcygF9DVGFG58A5iyV8AJsABml4PdMALbvcd9bD51d3NnsRGGAWcnY4J2gFMJZcC2tTSgB3bhgPAHkLK0sRGgARMOBNHT1gAzYTMlqyMnp%20XAQceCZMNvwUCQByajpGXqk4YhIjBsbmyoA6GggrAAokFAgnVpbCLfQsXG7gPoGGGGGASimBWfml8JbLXDF6YDWdroJD2mOzoA)

Comment: Type metadata is erased in transpilation and does not exist at runtime. You can't use a type as a value.

Comment: thanks , but what can I do now ?

Comment: You can create a type guard where you define yourself what the select object should look like.  Something like `(test.options == null || Array.isArray(test.options)) && (test.multiple == null && typeof test.multiple === "boolean")` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

Comment: And if you really want type validation, you can use zod https://github.com/colinhacks/zod

Comment: I'm confused why would you need that in typescript? I mean the typescript does the check for you...